# Filter multidimensional array based on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS. I have multidimensional array.

```
var myList = [{"Fund":"Edelweiss1","Rank":10},{"Fund":"Edelweiss","Rank":5}, {"Fund":"Edelweiss3","Rank":3}]
```

I want to filter "Rank" based on another array.

```
var rngarray = [6,10];
```

Filtering on rank should be `>=6 and <=10`

I tried this - `myList.filter(function (v) {rngarray.includes(v["Rank"])})` but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var myList = [{"Fund":"Edelweiss1","Rank":10},{"Fund":"Edelweiss","Rank":5}, {"Fund":"Edelweiss3","Rank":3}];

var rngarray = [6,10];

var filtered = myList.filter(item => item.Rank >= rngarray[0] && item.Rank <= rngarray[1]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Can you please explain why this does not work - myList.filter(function (v) {v.Rank >= rngarray[0] && v.Rank <= rngarray[1]})

Comment: `myList.filter(function (v) {v.Rank >` when you use `function` you need a `return`: `myList.filter(function (v) { return v.Rank >` - when using `item => ` without `{` the `return` is implied.